Replacing latex commands in edits
I have just rejected an edit of one of my posts. The edit wanted to replace numbers and symbols enclosed within mathematics delimiters, with equivalents not enclosed in latex markdown. An example is shown below:
pc$^{-2}$, (or kpc$^{-2}$) replaced with pc−2, (or kpc−2) or
$5.349\times 10^{51}$ g cm$^2$ s$^{-1}$ ($0.379\ M_\odot$ AU$^2$ yr$^{-1}$).
Replaced with
5.349 × 1051 g cm2 s−1 (0.379 M⊙ AU2 yr−1).
Cosmetically I can see why you might want to do this; my question is what would screen readers make of it?
If it's fine from an accessibility point of view then knock yourself out, there's another 2000-odd answers I've written with latex markdown.
EDIT:
I note that a default screen-reading player has appeared on Stack Exchange  pages (see screenshot below,  with screen reader play button). The reader at least identifies the mathematics markup by reading the $ symbol. Thus if someone understands latex markdown they can follow what is written.  The same reader fails to identify the alternative markdown as mathematics and does not mention the exponents at all.


I'm not clear if you're asking what screen readers would make of (1) Mathjax or (2) non-Mathjax ?

@StephenG I think screen readers can cope with mathjax

Well, I heard mobile users may have trouble with non-Mathjax version. On the other hand Mathjax needs a separate script, which many users of Noscript likely wouldn't bother to turn on. Another drawback of MJ is that it's pretty much not machine readable.

I tested this very posting with the inbuilt screen reader from my phone. Both versions were read identically. Identically badly, and I would have a hard time to understand the formula being read: "pc minus 2 or kpc minus 2 replaced with pc minus 2, or kpc minus 2 or 5349 times 1051 g cm 2 s minus 1..."
Yet from this experiment I recon that it doesn't make a difference (but I hope sincerely that more professional versions do make a difference).

There is now a screenreader that appears at the top of SE pages. It reads out the latex markdown, which I think is preferable.

I checked a free random questions, and did not find it on the mobile version. Can you be more specific where?

I see it on my mobile chrome browser (on SE pages) but not on the desktop version?

I see it neither on mobile nor desktop with my firefox browser.
